# bash script : syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, syntax-error

I'm not sure why that error is coming.

**Bash Script:**

```
while read line do
  grep "^$line$" sort-test1.txt >>matches.txt
done < sort-test2.txt
```

**Error:**

> syntax error at line 5: `done' unexpected

Please tell me why this error is occuring.

Comment: What do you get if you add line breaks or semi-colons, e.g. `while read line; do grep "^$line$" sort-test1.txt >>matches.txt; done < sort-test2.txt` ?

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/  Also `do` need to be new line

Comment: yes Kean , its working . but my expected output is coming wrong .

Comment: I want to read each line from new.txt and then loop through old.txt and see if there is a match values and if there is a match then write it out to in match file(new file).. if you have any idea on this please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be looking for simply `grep -xf sort-test2.txt sort-test1.txt`. If you still get incorrect output, probably your files have DOS line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to obtain the lines in common in 2 text files. You can execute a simple shell command:

`grep -F -x -f sort-test1.txt sort-test2.txt > matches.txt`

I think that it is what you need.

Comment: can you please let me know also how do i print unmatched values ?

Comment: I should do it in 2 steps, first get the lines in file2 that are not in file1 (grep -vxf sort-test2.txt sort-test1.txt > no_matches.txt) and afterward the opposite (grep -vxf sort-test1.txt sort-test2.txt >> no_matches.txt)

Comment: @garry : If you have a new problem, it helps all users of SO if you do not ask this in a comment, but post a completely new question for it.